# How do I get the line text from a JEditorPane for the line where my cursor is currently positioned?

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane and I put a mouse listener on it and can detect where the cursor is.

However, I would like to be able to **get the text of the line where my cursor is**. Is there a utility method I can use? If not, then how would I construct a method to do this?

```
        xmlEditor.addMouseListener(
            new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {  
                    try {
                        int caretPosition = xmlEditor.getCaretPosition();
                        int offset = 0;
                        int length = 0;
                        xmlEditor.getText(offset, length);
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(EZXPathFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a utility method I can use?

Never tried it with a JEditorPane but you might be able to use the `Utilities` class. You should be able to use methods like `getRowStart(...)` and `getRowEnd(...)`. Once you know the starting and ending offset you can get the text from the JEditorPane.

Something like:

```
int start = Utilities.getRowStart(textComponent, offset);
int end = Utilities.getRowEnd(textComponent, offset);
String text = textComponent.getText(start, end-start);
```